# Vue.js run an action after an element is created by v-if

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have an element that is loaded by a condition (v-if)

```
<div id="food-content" v-if="activeFood" v-cloak>
```

I load it with this:

```
        app7.activeFood = food;
```

I want, after it is instantiated, to a apply a class to animate it with this:

```
$("#food-content").addClass("animate-visible");
```

It is crucial that the class is only added after the element is created. If I just put it after loading it, the element won't be created yet so it does nothing, now the bad part is, if I wrap it with a nextTick function, it is created but with the class already making it not animate.

My question:
How to create the element like I'm doing, and after its create, add a class?

Answer (score 4):

Vue has a whole transitioning system for handling things like this: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

If you want to handle it manually you can use the lifecycle method `mounted`.

```
mounted () { 
  this.$el.classList.add('animate-visible')
}
```